# C++ BODMAS precedence

Tags: c++, oop

I need to implement a calculator using C++ OOP where I can input the expression format as (2+3-6*(5-3)+ 6)/4 as a string. The program should validate this and do the calculation according to  BODMAS precedence. Is there any inbuilt method in C++ for me to check the  BODMAS precedence of this string?

Comment: C++ will apply operator precedence to arithmetic expressions written in your code, but if you need to parse an expression entered by the user you'll need to write your own stack based solution or use a library.

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party library, it's not too difficult to write your own simple calculator parser... You need to use a stack. Searching for "Reverse Polish Notation" might also help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ does not provide any built-in parsing libraries, so you'll have look for a third-party one.  A [quick search](https://google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+parsing+library) shows quite a few options (e.g. if you use Boost, you could try [Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home)).